# Show featured image and excerpt of specific page on home page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I want to display featured image and excerpt of ie. ABOUT page on my home page. Is it possible to do this with pages not posts only?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in the meantime for the excerpt, now I need only featured image

add new function to functions.php:

```
//Display page excerpts
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function my_add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

and call the function in front-page.php>

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>

                                <?php 
                                    query_posts("page_id=2");
                                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post()
                                ?>
                                    <h1>Why US?</h1>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                                <?php
                                    endwhile; 
                                    wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the featured image, you need : 
1 - to modify your function, to add also thumbnail support

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_extend-page_functions' );
function my_extend-page_functions() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', array('excerpt', 'thumbnail' );
}
```

(Have a look on the codex page of all you can add http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support )

2- on the front-page, you can use `the_post_thumbnail()` 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: I managed to get the featured image to show up but I added something that is not needed as before the excerpt I am getting another excerpt of the posts from the blog :/ This is how my code looks like, any advices http://jsfiddle.net/m9cjf6p8/

Comment: You need to go through this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Generally you should not touch the "main query" but create secondary loops